# How would you go about installing and executing Helm on Gitlab CI/CD pipelines?

Tags: gitlab, yaml, openshift, gitlab-ci-runner, cicd

I am working to create a scheduler on Gitlab to execute a pipeline that deploys multiple applications to Openshift using helm. I have the pods ready and the scheduler set up,but I am unable to run helm commands. The pipeline fails out with the following error.

`++ echo '$ helm install chart-name helm/charts/--namespace dev # collapsed multi-line command' $ helm install chart-name helm/charts/ --namespace dev # collapsed multi-line command ++ helm install chart-name helm/charts/ --namespace dev bash: line 188: helm: command not found Cleaning up project directory and file based variables 00:01 ERROR: Job failed: exit status 1`

This is my code in the **gitlab.ci.yaml **. I attempted to add a helm image but it didn't seem to work, I was expecting to have the image therefore able to call the helm commands.

```
onboard-dev:
  stage: release
  tags: 
    - my-tag
  image:
    name: alpine/helm
    entrypoint: [""]
  script:
    - |
        PATH=$PATH:$(pwd)/bin
        oc login --token=$TOKEN  --insecure-skip-tls-verify=true --server=$MY_SERVER
        oc project dev
    - |
        helm install chart-name helm/charts --namespace dev
        helm upgrade --install chart-name helm/charts
```

What is the best way to go about achieving this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you install the `helm` cli inside the image you are using? If yes, you just forgot the PATH in the second script.